# How does one determine the genus of the ultraviolet curve from Seiberg-Witten curve?

Tags: supersymmetry, seiberg-witten-theory

In Gaiotto's construction of 4d ${\cal N}=2$ theories, one starts with 6d (2,0) theory and compactify it on the Riemann surface, which is called the ultraviolet curve of the ${\cal N}=2$ theory. In the case of $SU(2)$ ( $A_1$ theories ) with only regular punctures on Riemann surface, one can literally read off the structure of the ultraviolet curve from the quiver diagram.

When one considers asymptotically free theories or Argyres-Douglas theories, then the only way we could construct the ultraviolet curve is from the known Seiberg-Witten curve and the Seiberg-Witten differential. For instance, in the paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.1691.pdf the maximally superconformal point of $SU(n-1)$ theory with 2 flavors has the curve

\begin{equation}
{\tilde y}^2 = x^{n-2} + c_1 x^{n-3} + \dots + c_{n-2} + \frac{c_{n-1}}{x} + \frac{C_2}{x^2}
\end{equation}
and the SW differential $\lambda = {\tilde y} dx$ has poles at $0$ of degree $2$, and at $\infty$ with degree $n+2$. But how do we know the ultraviolet curve has genus $0$, $i.e.$, it is a sphere?

In general, starting with an arbitrary SW curve and the SW differential, how does one know the genus of the ultraviolet curve?